# Splitting of string

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: How to split a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/c-how-to-split-a-string)

Hi friends,i need to split a string containing comma seperated values and have to store each value to a variable to use further in the program.I have my code as following : but 
i am getting error in my code :

```
string myString = ........// i am getting the string from a function
string::iterator it = myString .begin();
while ( it != myString .end() )
 {
      if ( *it == ',' ) 
         {
           string element =*it++; //i can't do such type of conversion.but then how can 
                                    i get each value ?
           if(element.empty())
             {
             }
         } 
 }
```

Comment: See the answers to this question instead of implementing it again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/c-how-to-split-a-string

Comment: @Naveen: and more precisely, Feruccio's excellent answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/c-how-to-split-a-string/236234#236234 --> tokenize using iterators is cheap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do as following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string String = "Your,String,is,here";
char Separator = ',';

std::istringstream StrStream(String);
std::string Token;

while(std::getline(StrStream, Token, Separator))
{
  std::cout << Token << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using some available library as the boost string utilities http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/string_algo.html

If you need to implement it manually, I would not use iterators, but rather `std::string::find` to obtain the start and end positions of each one of the elements and then `std::string::substr`.

Answer (score 0):

Previously answered here,

[C++ ostream out manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288396/c-ostream-out-manipulation/5289170#5289170)

I do think there must be even more elegant solutions around here on SO, but this one at least includes unit tests :)